# How to add multiple subnets at once to cosmosdb through cli

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network

I am currently adding the subnet to cosmos db through this cli using the below script. Its working fine.

```
az cosmosdb network-rule add --subnet subnetid --ignore-missing-endpoint true --name dbName --resource-group rg_Group --subscription sub_id --virtual-network vnet_name
```

but now, I need to add couple more subnet from different Vnet to the same cosmos db, I can add another line to do. But, I am wondering is there a way I can pass just the resource ID's of the subnet like space delimeted. I can see from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/network-rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cosmosdb_network_rule_add) that there is --ids as optional parameter but resource Id's of cosmos.

Answer (score 0):

We have tested the cmdlets in our local environment, below statements are based on our analysis.

> `az cosmosdb network-rule add` I need to add couple more subnet from different Vnet to the same cosmos db, I can add another line to do.
> But, I am wondering is there a way I can pass just the resource ID's
> of the subnet like space delimeted. I can see from the link that there
> is --ids as optional parameter but resource Id's of cosmos.

Using `--ids` flags in the above cmdlet you cannot add multiple subnets/multiple virtual networks in virtual network rule of cosmos db.

if you want to add the same subnet as network rule to multiple cosmos database accounts you can pass those cosmos DB account resourceID using the `--ids` flags in the above cmdlet as shown below.

```
az cosmosdb network-rule add --ignore-missing-endpoint true --subnet <subnetResourceID> --ids <ResourceIDCosmosDb1> <ResourceIDCosmosDb2>
```

Here is the sample output for reference:

[image]

As suggested in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11350), you can use below cmdlet to add multiple subnets to a cosmos db

```
az cosmosdb update --resource-group <rgname> --virtual-network-rules <list of subsnets> --ids <cosmosdbResourceID>
```

Here is the reference documentation for [az cosmosdb update cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cosmosdb_update)